# Transposing part of a line: sed, awk, Perl, or cut, or what?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, text-processing, cut

Very new to this whole Unix thing. I'm currently using korn shell to try and format some lines of text.

My input has a couple of lines that look something like this

```
Date/Time        :- Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013
Host Name        :- HostNameHere
PIDS             :- NumbersNLetters
Product Name     :- ProductName
```

The desired output would be as follows:

```
Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" HostName="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" ProductName="ProductName"
```

So, I need to get rid of any spaces in the leftmost column, and throw everything in the rightmost column between quotations. I've looked at the cut command, and got this far:

```
Cut -f 1,2 -d -
```

Which might produce a result like `Date/Time:Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013`, which is close to what I want, but not quite. I wasn't sure if cut could let me add parentheses, and it doesn't look like I can remove spaces that way either.

`sed` seems like it might be closer to the answer, but I wasn't able to find through googling how I might just look for any pattern and not a specific one. I apologize for the incredibly basic question, but reading documentation only gets you so far before your brain starts to ache... If there are any better resources I should be looking at I would be happy to get pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Wondering for what do you need like extra-long-line output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl too :)

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/ +(?=.*:-)//g;s/^(.*?):-\s*(.*)\s*/$1="$2" /gm' < file.txt
```

produces from the @Endoro's input:

```
Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" HostName="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" ProductName="ProductName" Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" HostName="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" ProductName="ProductName" Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" HostName="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" ProductName="ProductName" Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" HostName="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" ProductName="ProductName"
```

or if you want one `\n` to the end

```
perl -0777 -nE 's/ +(?=.*:-)//g;s/^(.*?):-\s*(.*)\s*/$1="$2" /gm;say' < file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '{
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",$1);
    gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$2);
    print $1,$2
}
END { print "\n" }' FS=':- ' OFS='\=' ORS=' ' inputFile
```

**OR** a one-liner

```
awk '{gsub(/ /,"",$1);print $1,q$2q}END{print "\n"}' OFS='\=' q='"' FS=' +:- ' ORS=' ' file
```

Comment: maybe understand it wrong, but the OP want remove the spaces from the LHS, e.g. `Host Name :- HostNameHere` should be `HostName="HostNameHere"`

Comment: @jm666 Oops, the first solution does it. The one-liner didn't. Fixed it. Thank you for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 3):

Code is for GNU sed only:

```
sed -nr 's/(.*)\b\s+:-\s(.*)/\1="\2" /;H;s/.*//;${x;:k;s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/\1\2/g;tk;p}' file
```

---

..output example:

```
$cat file
Date/Time        :- Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013
Host Name        :- HostNameHere
PIDS             :- NumbersNLetters
Product Name     :- ProductName
Date/Time        :- Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013
Host Name        :- HostNameHere
PIDS             :- NumbersNLetters
Product Name     :- ProductName
Date/Time        :- Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013
Host Name        :- HostNameHere
PIDS             :- NumbersNLetters
Product Name     :- ProductName
Date/Time        :- Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013
Host Name        :- HostNameHere
PIDS             :- NumbersNLetters
Product Name     :- ProductName

$sed -nr "s/(.*)\b\s+:-\s(.*)/\1=\"\2\" /;H;s/.*//;${x;:k;s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/\1\2/g;tk;p}" file
Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" Host Name="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" Product Name="ProductName" Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" Host Name="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" Product Name="ProductName" Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" Host Name="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" Product Name="ProductName" Date/Time="Monday June 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013" Host Name="HostNameHere" PIDS="NumbersNLetters" Product Name="ProductName"
```

In some environments `"`double quotes`"` must be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: overly complicated then :-). The following simply chaining works generically `sed 's/\s*://' input | sed 's/- / "/' | sed 's/$/" /' | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: @FredrikPihl my code does'n brick, the line bricks before :-)

Comment: I'm reluctant to give you a +1, compare your solution to the simplicity of awk in this case. Perhaps later for sed-masturbation :-)

Comment: ditto: The OP want remove the spaces from `Host Name`

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this to get you started

```
awk '{
  if (NR % 4)
printf("%s ", $0)
  else
printf("%s\n", $0)
}' file
```

found here http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/115070-how-can-i-join-three-lines-into-one-unix.html

then use cut

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to apply three distinct transformations on your input:

1. On every line, remove any whitespace before `:-`.
2. On every line, replace `:-` followed by whitespace with `="`.
3. On every line, add `"` to the end.
4. Replace newlines with spaces.

It's always a good idea to create a plan like this before trying to come up with the right commands.

**To execute the first step**, using `sed` would be the best option. `sed` works with regular expressions, which you can read about on [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Because we only want to remove whitespace *before* the `:-` our expression needs to be aware of its surroundings. To this end, one might use a [*zero-width lookbehnd assertion*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), to check that the pattern (whitespace, denoted by `\s`) does not replace anything after `:-` on a line. However `sed` doesn't support this feature of regular expressions, we'll use a perl one-liner instead.

```
perl -pe 's/\s*(?=.*:-)//g'
```

This means: replace any whitespace followed by `:-` after any amount of characters, by the empty string. The `g` stands for *global* and causes the pattern replace all matches, instead of just the first one. Using `perl -pe` in is identical to `sed` but allows for fancier regular expressions.

**Step two** is a little simpler: replace `:-` plus any whitespace by `=`.

```
sed 's/:-\s*/="/'
```

**Step three** is super-simple:

```
sed 's/$/"/'
```

Here, `$` means *end of line*. By the way, two or more `sed` commands can be combined into one using `;` as a delimiter:

```
sed 's/:-\s*/="/;s/$/"/'
```

This'll be marginally faster. I could tell you to use `sed` for **the last step** too, but I'll take this opportunity to show you another core command: `tr`. `tr` is short for *translate* and replaces any single character by another. It is much quicker than sed.

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

Here, `\n` stands for the newline character (ASCII code `0x0a`).

**So, putting all pieces together:**

```
cat input | perl -pe 's/\s*(?=.*:-)//g' | sed 's/:-\s*/="/;s/$/"/' | tr '\n' ' '
```

For further study, you might want to read the manual pages of `sed` and `tr`. Enter these commands to do so:

```
man sed
man tr
```

Comment: `sed` does support all these things you say, it doesn't.

Comment: Well, it does not seem to support lookaround using the Perl syntax. But there might be other ways to obtain the same results, like the command you posted. Personally, I would recommend mastering Perl-style regular expressions as they are in the end more useful than any `sed` magic will ever be.

Comment: Anyway, it's a pretty fancy command that you came up with. So, if you're able to master the syntax, good for you. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/ (\S*:-.*)$/\1/;ta;s/:-\s*/="/;s/$/"/;1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/\n/ /g' file
```

- `:a;s/ (\S*:-.*)$/\1/;ta` remove any spaces left of `:-`
- `s/:-\s*/="/` replace `:-` with `="`
- `s/$/"/` insert a `"` at end-of-line.
- `1h;1!H` for the first line insert the pattern space (PS) into the hold space (HS). There after append the PS to the HS.
- `$!d` all but the last line delete the PS and read the next line into the PS.
- `x` on the last line swap the HS for the PS
- `s/\n/ /g` replace all newlines with spaces and print out the resulting one line.